# char array stores null values

Tags: c#, to-char

I am currently doing some code challenges and i have run into a problem which i cant find a solution to.

```
public static bool SelfDescribing(string num)
{

    char[] digit = num.ToArray();
    int bound = digit.Count();

    for (int i = 0; digit.Length != 0 && i < bound; i++)

    {

        int arrLength = 0;
        var count = num.Count(x => x == digit[i]);
        if (count == i)
        {
            arrLength++;
            if (arrLength == bound)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }          
    }
    return false;
}
```

everytime i try to pass a string to this it stores the separate values as null im my digit array. example is that i tried to pass the value test1 = "1211"

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with this code

Comment: How you recognized a `null` value? Did you get any Exceptions?

Comment: @un-lucky to evaluate whether a number is selfdescribing, but my current problem is that i cant even store the value in my array. i wanna use the values from this array to track the number of occurences of said value

Comment: @Fabio using debug i saw that digit was = null

Comment: I've tried your code, in debug digit assume values digit = new char[] { '1','2','1',1'} ... Where is the problem.

Comment: @Othello.netdev okay then the problem must be somewhere outside my code, since when i run it it doesnt assume any value although it do create char[4] array which i think implies that it recognizes the data

Comment: i'm not a math eagle, what number should return true?

Comment: One obvious problem with this code is that `arrLength`, whatever it is meant to be, can only assume the values `0` and `1`. It seems to be compared against (effectively) the length of the string - so this code can only ever return `true` for a string of length `1`. But I'm really not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: 1210 would be true since 0 occurs 1 time, 1 occurs 2 times, 2 occurs 1 time and 3 occurs 0 time. its comparing the place in its array with the value.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the reason that i didnt explain my code further was that i havent gotten to the formatting of given number, since i cant even store them in my array. the code is meant to evaluate the number of occurences of each member of the char array, and if they match the current iteration of the loop then return true

Comment: @Claudi check my answer.

Comment: Please try to explain in detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but try putting int arrLength = 0; outside your for loop

Comment: debug at least one time your code before ask please. with 1210 var count = num.Count(x => x == 1);  (first iteration) fail the first check because 2 instances of 1 is != of 0 (i as first iteration).

Comment: @Othello.netdev I get that there might be some problem with what im returning, but i only tried to get an answer to why i couldnt store data in my array. i get now that i might have submitted a poorly formatted question but i tried to give some context to where i was declaring my array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is wrong for multiple reason:

1- You're comparing the count and the index, you should compare the count with the value in that index.

`if (count == i)` should be `if (count == char.GetNumericValue(digit[i]))`

2- You should count the index and not the character stored at that index:

3- Most important:  you should return false when you **find a mismatch**. You don't need to compare the count success matching digits.

`num.Count(x => x == digit[i]);` should be `num.Count(x => x == char.Parse(i.ToString()));`

### You can fix your method like this :

(It is not a preferred logic, check alternative below it)

```
public static bool SelfDescribing(string num)
{

    char[] digit = num.ToArray();
    int bound = digit.Count();

    int sucessCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; digit.Length != 0 && i < bound; i++)
    {
        var count = num.Count(x => x == char.Parse(i.ToString()));
        if (count == char.GetNumericValue(digit[i]))
        {
            sucessCount++;
        }
    }
    return sucessCount == digit.Length;
}
```

To optimize your method:

```
public static bool SelfDescribing(string num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
        var count = num.Count(x => x == char.Parse(i.ToString()));
        if (count != char.GetNumericValue(num[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

### Alternative working logic:

```
public static bool SelfDescribing(string num)
{
    bool result = true;

    int[] numbersArray = num.ToArray().Select(x => (int)char.GetNumericValue(x)).ToArray();

    var occurences = numbersArray.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

    for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.Length; i++)
    {
        int occ;

        if (occurences.TryGetValue(i, out occ))
        {
            if(occ != numbersArray[i])
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (i == 0)
                continue;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: well this works, but it still doesnt answer my question to why i couldnt store values in my array. but from this code i think im able to debug it, since iy might have something to do with they way i formatted the data.

Comment: @Claudi i updated with problems from your code

Comment: this answers my question, apparantly i wa reading the debug information wrong. therefore i jumped to the wrong conclusion of what the problem was, by reviewing my code with you input i was able to figure out the debugging info.

Comment: @Claudi I posted multiple alternative methods, you can check them out. It is better to break out of your loops once you first know you have the result. This is better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Will this give you the expected result? You haven't explained what you are trying to do, but it seems arrLength should only be initialized once, probably.

```
public static bool SelfDescribing(string num)
{
   char[] digit = num.ToArray();
   int bound = digit.Count();
   int arrLength = 0;

   for (int i = 0; digit.Length != 0 && i < bound; i++)
   {
        var count = num.Count(x => x == digit[i]);
        if (count == i)
        {
            arrLength++;
            if (arrLength == bound)
            {
                return true;
            }
         }          
   }
   return false;
 }
```